# Is it possible to use an array to define Type with Zod?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

With Zod, I want to get an array that I can access, and re-use that array to define a type as well:

```
const TSchema= z.enum(‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’); //hey, let's re-use this array as below!
type T = z.infer<typeof TSchema>;
//Gives me ‘type 'a’ | 'b' | 'c' <<<<<<<
//which is what I want, good!
```

However, if I do:

```
const arr = [‘a’,’b’,’c’] as readonly [string, …string[]]; 
const TSchema= z.enum(arr);
type T = z.infer<typeof TSchema>;
//Gives me ‘type T = string’, oh noes! <<<<<<<
//Why has the type changed? 
//I want the union literal type above!
```

Although I am using Zod to do it, I think this is not a Zod-specific question, I feel this is a generic typescript question. Please take a look for me :)

Comment: What about `const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']  as const`? As for 'why has the type changed': well, you used `as readonly [string, ...string[]]`, that means you have manually changed the type to `readonly [string, ...string[]]`

Answer (score 1):

use the `.enum` property to access the content, and transform it to the array:

```
const TSchema = z.enum(['a', 'b', 'c']);
const values = Object.values(TSchema.enum) // ("a" | "b" | "c")[]

TSchema.enum.a // "a"
```

Comment: Thanks! your way also works the other way around. I like qrsngky's solution it is more like what I am expecting in the first place.